# make a type name out of two macros in free pascal

Tags: macros, freepascal

In Pascal you can use macros to change a name of a type. This is very useful when you want to use an include as a template. 

CustomList.inc:

```pascal
TCustomList = class
  ...
  property Items[ Index: Integer ]: TCustomItem read GetItems; default;
end;

TCustomListEnumerator = class     
  ...
```

Right now I have to change each name with a define in the above listing:

```pascal
{$MACRO ON}
{$DEFINE TCustomList:= TTestItemList}
{$DEFINE TCustomItem:= TTestItem}
{$DEFINE TCustomListEnumerator:= TTestItemListEnumerator}
{$INCLUDE CustomList.inc}
```

Is it somehow possible to glue two macros to one type identifier?

```pascal
{$MACRO ON}
{$DEFINE TCustomItem:= TTestItem}
{$INCLUDE CustomList.inc}
```

CustomList.inc:

```pascal
{$DEFINE TCustomList:= TCustomItem + List}
{$DEFINE TCustomListEnumerator:= TCustomItem + ListEnumerator}
...
```

The above listing is interpreted as TTestItem + List and not TTestItemList. Is there some way to append some postfix to the macro?

Comment: This appears to be specific to FPC; it's certainly not anything I remember from standard Pascal.

Comment: As I understand the FPC macros expanded 'as is', using previousely defined macros, so {$DEFINE TCustomList:=TCustomItem + List} will be interpreted as `TTestItem + List` in your example, not as `TTestItemList`. I not sure about 'macros expressions'. So you need to write something like `{$IFDEF A}{$DEFINE B:=C}{$ELSE}{$DEFINE B:=D}{$ENDIF}`

Comment: Thanks for your response,
You are right with the interpretation of the macro, i edited the question to clearify this. What you wrote in the second part does not solve this problem, right? Are you saying that it is not possible or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: The macro facility is very limited. It is mostly meant and used for calling conventions (stdcall on windows, cdecl on Linux) and iirc lazarus uses it to turn logging on and off. It is not really meant for metaprogramming

Comment: This was my guess as well that it is just not possible, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks!